# will an instance variable of other class be destroyed when activity is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, class, variables, instance

I am new to Java and Android.

Please don't hesitate to explain if my question is silly..

I have a reference to another class

```
someclass x = new someclass()
```

in activity (MainActivity.java) class and that class(someclass) has one static variable.

Is that reference variable(instance variable of class) destroyed when the activity is destroyed?

I'm asking this question because the class holds some static variables....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` variables exist whether objects of that class exist or not. So the value will be there even if `MainActivity`'s `onDestroy()` gets called. If you have 100 other activities, they will **also** have access to the static variable.

Comment: someclass x = new someclass(). What about variable 'x' - that is instance of someclass . will it be destroyed when activity destroyed?

Comment: If the reference to the object is not passed somewhere else, there is no longer a way to access the instance variable and it will be GC'd with the object

Comment: @svenoaks What my question is i have reference of the someclass in MainActivity, will this reference and all the variable of that class be cleared from memory when MainActivity destroyed? I am not clear with statement "If the reference to the object is not passed somewhere else"  how to pass the object of class from an activity .It is not possible i think because that object is not seriablizable one...

Comment: Sure it is possible, it doesn't need to be Serializable. You could pass the someclass instance to another class that keeps a reference in another thread, or to static someclass variable somewhere. Then the instance variables of that someclass instance will be kept alive past the destruction of the Activity. The important thing is the instance variables are associated with a particular instance of the class, if you have a reference to that instance, you can still access them.

Comment: @svenoaks-- In activity class i have created that reference object ,will it be destroyed when activity destroyed?(only in that particular activity i am asking)..but we can keep reference in some other class that i know...what about reference created in MainActivity after that activity destruction...